# Struct not recognised when declared in header file

Tags: c, struct, namespaces, declaration, function-declaration

I am programming my ESP32 devices and stumbled across this weird issue and I cannot get my head around. All I want is to declare a struct in my header file and then initialise it in my source file.

My header file:

```
struct response_sensor_info{
    uint16_t temp;
    bool door_state;
    bool motion;
};
//declare some function prototype that is going to use that structure
void send_multiple_responses(response_sensor_info sensor_info_struct);
```

my .c file:

```
#include "my_header.h"

struct response_sensor_info sensor_info_struct;

void send_multiple_responses(response_sensor_info sensor_info_struct){
//do something with the struct here
    
}
```

I cannot compile my code because of the following error:

```
error: unknown type name 'response_sensor_info'
 void send_multiple_responses(response_sensor_info sensor_info_struct);
```

Can someone help me understand what is the issue? I have clearly declared the struct but it is not recognised in function prototype

Comment: `send_multiple_responses(response_sensor_info sensor_info_struct)` -> `send_multiple_responses(struct response_sensor_info sensor_info_struct)`

Comment: There is no type `response_sensor_info`  defined anywhere in your code. What you define is `struct response_sensor_info`. This means you must add the `struct` keyword to the tag name.

Comment: In C you need to manually define a type `response_sensor_info`:  `typedef struct response_sensor_info response_sensor_info;` or you need to use `struct`

Comment: you either need to put in `struct` before every struct type in every declaration, or just `typedef  struct whatever_struct { ... } whatever` to have it available as a `whatever` type.

Comment: Yes thanks :) I have read somewhere that it is better to avoid typedefs because they make it more difficult to keep track of structs. I try to use structs everywhere and not typedefs

Answer (score 1):

You do not have the type specifier `response_sensor_info`. You jave the type specifier `struct response_sensor_info`.

So the function must be declared like

```
void send_multiple_responses(struct response_sensor_info sensor_info_struct);
```

You could introduce an alias for the type specifier `struct response_sensor_info` for example like

```
struct response_sensor_info{
    uint16_t temp;
    bool door_state;
    bool motion;
};

typedef struct response_sensor_info response_sensor_info;
```

In this case your function declaration will be correct.

It seems that actually the function should be declared like

```
void send_multiple_responses(struct response_sensor_info *sensor_info_struct);
```

that is it should accept an object of the structure type by reference through a pointer to it if you are going to change the object within the function. In any case passing by reference prevents creating a copy of an object of the structure type.

If the function does not change the passed object then it should be declared like

```
void send_multiple_responses( const struct response_sensor_info *sensor_info_struct);
```

Also be sure whether it is necessary to define an object of the structure type in file scope.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  
```void send_multiple_responses(struct response_sensor_info sensor_info_struct){

    printf("sensor_info_struct = %u \n",sensor_info_struct.door_state);

}```
I can now sucesfully call the function in my main.c when I declared it with struct word. Since this structure is initialised in my other  .c file, in my main.c I have initialised it with extern keyword. 

Please can you elaborate what you meant regarding your last sentence: Also be sure whether it is necessary to define an object of the structure type in file scope.

Comment: @TheBestPlayer Usually it is a bad idea when objects are defined inside file scopes.

Comment: Please can you explain more what you mean? Where should I define my object? For example I have 2 source files: main.c and bluetooth.c . I want to be able to use the same object sensor_info_struct in both files

Comment: @TheBestPlayer You could define it for example in main.

Comment: @TheBestPlayer Each object should be defined in minimal scope where it is used.

Comment: But if I define it in  main I also must define it as extern in bluetooth.c right?

Comment: @TheBestPlayer I do not know why you need to do this. Maybe you need to redesign your program. You can access the object through functions.

Comment: If I create my object in main.c I cannot access it in my bluetooth.c because the object is defined in main.c and bluetooth.c does not know anything about its existence unless I declare it as extern in bluetooth.c

Comment: @TheBestPlayer I do not know how your program looks but I suspect that it can be redesigned and there is no need to define the object in file scope.

Comment: Imagine I create object in my main.c ```struct response_sensor_info sensor_info_struct = {10,20,30};``` 
Now I want to use this object in bluetooth.c. In my bluetooth.c I have a function:
```check_sensor_values(struct response_sensor_info sensor_info_struct){
printf("sensor_info_struct temperature = %i \n",sensor_info_struct.temperature);
}```
Now the above wont work because bluetooth.c does not know anything about sensor_info_struct

Comment: @TheBestPlayer I do not know why the whole file bluetooth.c needs an access to the object and why it can not be accessed through functions being defined in main.

Comment: @TheBestPlayer I do not see your program so I can say nothing whether it is required to define the object globally. But in general you should avoid such program designs.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. Let me give you an example. For instance now I am writing Bluetooth parser code. For example I send some hex value to my microcontroller from the mobile phone, and the bluetooth must respond based on what hex value I have sent. For example if I send 0x00 the bluetooth must send me back the state for thermostat. If I send 0x11, the bluetooth must send me back the state of GPIO's. This means that bluetoot.c must know everything about thermostat and GPIO. So I must declare the required structs or variables in bluetooth.c as extern. Isn't that correct design?

Comment: @TheBestPlayer It is too abstract and itself represents another question.

Comment: You are right. Anyways, thank you for helping with the struct problem.